# JXP API for JAVA

Tags: java, jxl

I want to make a java program which write in excel file 2 int vars and get their sum (calculated in excel);
The problem is that the 2 vars are correctly inserted in excel file but the sum returned is 0: the sum is updated only if we open the execl file!!!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCell;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
public class GC {
public static String Filename="exemple.xls";
public static String FilenameTemp="exempleTemp.xls";
static String[] tab={"1","1"};

 /* On créé un nouveau worbook et on l'ouvre en écriture */
static Workbook workbook = null;
static WritableWorkbook copy = null;
static /* On créé une nouvelle feuille (test en position 0) et on l'ouvre en écriture */
Sheet sheet1 = null;
static WritableSheet sheet2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(Filename));
    } catch (BiffException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(FilenameTemp), workbook);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* On créé une nouvelle feuille (test en position 0) et on l'ouvre en écriture */
    sheet1 = workbook.getSheet(0);
    sheet2 = copy.getSheet(0);
//      
    ecritureExcel(tab);
    System.out.println(lectureExcel(0,2));

}

public static String lectureExcel(int c,int l)
{

    String contenu=null;
    try {

        /* On peut également le faire avec getCell(nomCellule) */
        Cell a = sheet2.getCell(c,l);

        /* On peut récupérer le contenu d'une cellule en utilisant la méthode getContents() */
        contenu = a.getContents();

    } 
    finally {
                    try {
                        if(copy!=null)
                            copy.close();
                    } catch (WriteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
    return contenu;
}

public static void ecritureExcel(String[] s)
{
    try {           
        ecritureVar(0,0,s[0]);ecritureVar(0,1,s[1]);
        /* On ecrit le classeur */
        copy.write(); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void ecritureVar(int c,int l, String s)
{

/* Creation d'un champ au format texte */
Label label = new Label(c,l,s);
//WritableCellFormat newFormat = new  WritableCellFormat(sheet.getWritableCell(c,l).getCellFormat());
//label.setCellFormat(newFormat);
try {
    sheet2.addCell(label);
} catch (WriteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```